# How to pass any UUID in a function in unit testing in mockito?

Tags: java, generics, junit, mockito, testng

I have a function func() which accepts UUID as an argument. I am making a unit test for which I need to return a specific value for any UUID value passed to func(). How can I make it work for any UUID type value (just like `anyString()` for any string, `anyInt()` for any integer, etc)?

I have already tried:

```
when(obj.func(any(UUID.class)).thenReturn(null);
```

It gives the following error:

`The method any(Class<UUID>) is ambiguous for the type <Test_Class_Name>`

where Test_Class_Name is the name of the class where I am writing the unit tests.

func() is an overloaded function : func(String) and func(UUID)

Comment: Have you tried explicitly casting so that the right method can be trivially found? (i.e. `when(obj.func((UUID) any(UUID.class)).thenReturn(null);`)

Comment: Yes did that, doesn't work.

Comment: What version of Mockito are you using?

Comment: As pointed out in the comments, multiple import of any (Matchers and CoreMatchers ) was the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For any other type you can use `any()`. This will match an argument of given type:

```
any(UUID.class)
```

You can find more information in the [documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.7/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html).

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't work:
when(obj.func(any(UUID.class)).thenReturn(null);

It shows the following error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Matcher<UUID> to UUID

Comment: @AbdulAhad did you try with no parameter? Just `any()`?

Comment: The issue is that func is an overloaded function, hence it creates an issue of ambiguity. func(String) and func (UUID). 
Also update that the error is : The method any(Class<UUID>) is ambiguous for the type <Class Name>
This is in both cases, the previous error was due to brackets mismatch.

Comment: Sorry but I can't as it is not a personal project.

Comment: @AbdulAhad Try `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any(UUID.class)`. It seems that you call some other `any` method.

Comment: Thanks! It works with Matchers.any(). Any idea on how I can disallow null values?

Comment: @AbdulAhad try `import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.*`

Comment: Yeah I found the issue, any was imported from both Matchers and CoreMatchers. Hence the ambiguity. Although I cannot import ArgumentMatchers but this works.
How can I eliminate null values from any?

Comment: just add an assertion that there was no call with null parameter

Comment: `Mockito.verify(obj).func(ArgumentMatchers.isNotNull())` or `Mockito.verify(obj, never()).func(ArgumentMatchers.isNull())`